# JaCoCo doesn't ignore Lombok generated code

Tags: java, code-coverage, lombok, jacoco

I want to test my Java code and measure the code coverage with JaCoCo.

I'm using Lombok and for e.g getters or builders I get 0% code coverage. So I tried to put a `lombok.config` file in my root project - but nothing changed.

I also tried to use lombok.Builder and so on and remove the imported Lombok classes for this class but nothing changed.

See: [addLombokGeneratedAnnotation on lombok.config doesn't ignore Lombok Annotations on Jacoco report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65412697/addlombokgeneratedannotation-on-lombok-config-doesnt-ignore-lombok-annotations)

Has anybody an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I am using IntelliJ IDEA, and I encountered an issue where running tests from the IDE did not compile the entire project. As a result, the configuration file (*lombok.config*) was not recognized as a change. However, when I selected `Build -> Rebuild` Project my changes started appearing correctly.