# Excluding lombok coverage in Sonar does not work

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, lombok, jacoco

I am trying to exclude Lombok coverage in Sonar.

This is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
//...
    id "org.sonarqube" version "4.0.0.2929"
    id 'jacoco'
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
    }
}
test.finalizedBy jacocoTestReport

//...
```

To exclude those classes I tried the following steps:

1. I created a lombok.config file in this path: *src\main\resources*
2. I added the following properties:

```
# This tells lombok this directory is the root,
# no need to look somewhere else for java code.
config.stopBubbling = true
# This will add the @lombok.Generated annotation
# to all the code generated by Lombok,
# so it can be excluded from coverage by jacoco.
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

3. I added this in build.gradle:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    // ...
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: ['lombok/**'])
        }))
    }
}
```

4. Cleaning the project before executing the sonar task:

```
gradlew.bat clean build test --debug sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=" + service + " -Dsonar.projectName=" + service + " -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.token=" + global_token
```

Unfortunately for some reason after executing the sonar task to analyze the project,

I **still have the Lombok code uncovered**:

[image: uncovered code]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addLombokGeneratedAnnotation on lombok.config doesn't ignore Lombok Annotations on Jacoco report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65412697/addlombokgeneratedannotation-on-lombok-config-doesnt-ignore-lombok-annotations)

Comment: Unfortunatley not, I tried as the other users suggested to add a random ```@lombok.Data```. But the thing is that I already clean the project before lunching the sonar task ```gradlew.bat clean build test --debug sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=" + service + " -Dsonar.projectName=" + service + " -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.token=" + global_token```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lombok.config **must be in the root** of the project, not in *src\main\resources*